# SQL Server - Batch Processing and 1 second waits

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on updating over 100 million rows in a table. In order to reduce the number of rows that are locked (or even a table lock), I'm processing the updates with a combination of a while-loop and incrementing of 10k rows at a time.

I am running this on SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @last int = 10000000

WHILE @i <= @last
BEGIN
    UPDATE mytbl (ROWLOCK)
    SET foo = null
    WHERE id BETWEEN @i AND @i + 10000

    SET @i += 10000

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
END
```

Does the 1 second wait in the code do anything in terms of improved performance, committing/flushing the transaction, or releasing transaction locks?

Comment: I apologize in advance. This was published on my phone so there may be some syntax errors....

Comment: The only benefit of the `WAITFOR` here is to play nicer with other concurrent activity against the table. It will only slow down the batching, not improve performance.

Comment: If the clustered index is on `id` then pagelock will certainly be faster. Maybe Snapshot Isolation level. Or you could disable lock escalation

Comment: Since there are no explicit transactions in this code, I could assume that SQL Server uses [autocommit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/auto-commit-mode?view=sql-server-ver15) transactions, so each your SQL statement is executed in a separate 'silent' transaction started and committed by the server. So, this `WAITFOR` doesn't make much sense in the case of transactions: the X locks are released each time the `UPDATE` clause completes.

Comment: Also, I would reduce the number of 10000 rows since the SQL Server escalates the lock if there are [more than 5000 locks](https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/) of a single level acquired, and in the case of `UPDATE` clause X locks are acquired which are held until the transaction ends, so most probably, the server will escalate it to the table level which you want to avoid.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend disabling lock escalation since it could [prevent queries to execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/resolve-blocking-problems-caused-lock-escalation) if the lock memory grows too much.

Comment: Premature optimization is never a good idea. Don't use lock hints until you know they are needed and are helpful. And note that your code updates 10,000,000 rows. Is that a typo or is your goal to update every row in the table? And obviously you should filter the update so that you only set foo where it is currently NOT null.

Comment: @Kangaxx  agreed, I recall reading somewhere that SQL Server will escalate the lock to a table lock if there are more than 5000 rows affected. I also agree with you on that the WAITFOR felt out of place given the way how the [autocommit] transactions are held and released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: "In order to reduce the number of rows that are locked (or even a table lock)..."

In general, you have a good approach.  Recommendations:

1. I recommend that you wrap the UPDATE in an explicit transaction.  Commit the transaction on each iteration. Otherwise you risk having a 100,000 million row transaction. Explicit transactions mean that I know that it committed. BEGIN TRAN ... UPDATE ... COMMIT TRAN. I use explicit transactions for this type of work every time.
2. Reduce the increment from 10,000.  I use 1,000 in all cases. You can run tests to determine the exact number that will trigger table lock. You can read Microsoft guidelines for lock escalation for 2012 (lock escalation differs by version).  But, my goal, when I do this, is to never table lock. Emphasis on "never". I just use 1,000 and sleep better at night.  I recommend 1,000 for you. But, your mileage may vary.
3. Remove the WAITFOR. For the purposes of this loop, it only adds hours to the run time (10,000 seconds for the original 10,000 increment on 100 million rows).

I hope that helps.  I have done between 50 and 100 of these on tables into the billions of rows.  The keys (as noted above):  never table lock and commit every iteration to keep the transaction small.  Small transactions are your friend for many reasons.